# How to manage Buttons being disabled/enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

In my app I have a view with 3 textfields. Until they are ALL filled out, I want my button to be disabled. In the storyboard I left it enabled, but then in my ViewDidLoad I added this:

```
 if (amtYouOwe.text.length == 0 && personYouOweMoney.text.length == 0 && self.cellNum.text.length == 0)
{
    saveButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

Even if all the fields were filled out my button was disabled..So then I tried to put it in my IBAction save button. This time I got the opposite result. No matter what my button was enabled. Even if all the textfields were blank. I believe my code is correct, I'm just trying to find the perfect place to put it....

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function to enable/disable saveButton as

```
-(void)enableDisableSave{
    if (amtYouOwe.text.length == 0 && personYouOweMoney.text.length == 0 && self.cellNum.text.length == 0){
        saveButton.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        saveButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Write a delegate method of textField, assign your view controller as delegate to all textfield, write following delegate method and call that method in that and bingo..

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self enableDisableSave];
}
```

Comment: try to put break point around `enableDisableSave` method and check whether it goes into if condition or not. Also check you have properly assigned delegate as well.

Comment: Ah I see the code works after I'm done editing the textfields like it should, but what I want is when the view loads, the button is disabled until the textfields are entered

Comment: just write a single statement on `viewDidLoad` as `saveButton.enabled=NO` so it should work. Also You need to update code of the method as I have edited to make it enable again.

Comment: after I did that it remains disabled no matter what

Answer (score 0):

You should add button enable/disable control in UITextField delegate methods. Every time a text field being edited, check all the text fields' length and change button status.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want real time checking, use this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ..
    // your code
    // ..

    [self addTextChangedEvent];
    [self toggleSaveButtonStatus];
}

- (void)addTextChangedEvent {

    [amtYouOwe addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [personYouOweMoney addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [self.cellNum addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self toggleSaveButtonStatus];
}
- (void)toggleSaveButtonStatus {

    int youOweLength = amtYouOwe.text.length;
    int personYouOweLength = personYouOweMoney.text.length;
    int cellNumLength = self.cellNum.text.length;
    saveButton.enabled = youOweLength > 0 && personYouOweLength > 0 && cellNumLength > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write in .pch file

This macro does not allow white space..

```
#define allTrim( object ) [object stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] ]
```

then write delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self enableDisableSave];
}
```

Write a function to enable/disable saveButton as

```
-(void)enableDisableSave{
    if ([allTrim(amtYouOwe.text) length] == 0 && [allTrim(personYouOweMoney.text) length] == 0 && [allTrim(self.cellNum.text) length] == 0){
        saveButton.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        saveButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!!!